# Common hydrogen bonded liquids

Tags: hydrogen, hydrogen-bond, liquid-crystals

For some experiments I need liquids with and without hydrogen bond which are pure or highly concentrated. I have only found $\ce{HNO3, CH3COOH}$ concentrated. But i need more liquids. And it would be better if they are common.

Also it's even harder to find non H-bonded liquids. There's oil but common cooking oil is a mixture, I need oils as pure as possible.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with water?  Or (diethyl) ether?

Stand back and think about what makes things hydrogen-bonded, or not.